# Gstreamer add a timestamp from a NTP clock

Tags: timestamp, gstreamer, ntp

I am using GStreamer to send over UDP multiples camera streams, H264 encoded.
I would like to add a timestamp in the metadata from a NTP clock.
On the Client side I need to save these multiple streams and be able to synchronise them later with these timestamps.
As I will be using multiples Jetsons (as streaming sources) carrying multiples cameras each, I will need to use a common clock which I can get from a NTP server.

What is the best way to do add a timestamp from a NTP clock in the metadata ?

Note: I am using GStreamer 1.14.5

Comment: NTP and POSIX UNIX timestamps are not unique across leap seconds, so that could be a glitch/bug.